# Stock Options in Exchange for Salary

Tags: stocks, options, salary, employee-stock-options, job-offer

I received an offer letter with with the option to convert part of the salary to stock options as per the below table. Base salary is ₪33K/month (Israeli Shekel). Be aware of '₪' vs '$' in some columns. As of this writing the exchange rate is 1$ = 3.7₪.

[image: 1]

Additionally the letter states:

Based on current run-rate, price per share is $2,675.

Exercise price will be at 90% discount of the last (at the time of signing) round price. If you are an American citizen, exercise price will be according to 409a valuation (~$800 per-share).

**End of Offer Details**

I would appreciate any help in understanding this information. What I'm mainly confused about is:

- Does "Run-Rate Value" mean current value or something else?
- Does "Exercise price will be at 90% discount" mean I pay 90% or 10%?
- Does "the last (at the time of signing) round price" refer to the $2,675/share stated above?
- What is the significance of the 4th and 5th columns?
- Does it make sense to forfeit some salary continually and indefinitely, in exchange for a discount in stock? It seems to me, intuitively at least, that eventually the loss in salary deduction will outweigh the gain of discounted stock.
- I am an American citizen, what is a 409a valuation?

Thank you to anyone who can help me understand this.

Comment: When you asked the company about this, what information did they give you?

Comment: WHEN do you expect it will all happen?  Do you have to hang in for a year?  Five years?  That's the crux.

Comment: "run-rate" means "Guess".

Comment: That's all the info they gave me.  They're private now, no telling when they'll have a liquidity event.